# Selecting an option from one drop down populates other input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to figure out how to populate other  tags with a specific text after selecting from a drop down.

So if the drop down and another drop down below it the following should happen. When you choose "A" from dropDown1, dropDown2 should populate with "You chose A". If you choose "B" dropDown2 should say "You chose B". Same goes for "C"

Here is a sample code below.

```
<html>
<body>
<form>

 <select id="dropDown1">
    <option value = "A">A</option>
    <option value = "B">B</option>
    <option value = "C">C</option>
 </select>

<select id="dropDown2">
    <option value="You chose A">You chose A</option>
    <option value="You chose B">You chose B</option>
    <option value="You chose C">You chose C</option>
</select>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you could show some code that be awesome or if you could point me in the right direction where I can find the answer that be awesome to.

Comment: Are the values in select 2 going to be predefined than selected based upon select 1 input or are you wanting to dynamically add options to select 2 based upon user input in select 1?

Comment: Yeah select 2 will be dependent on select 1. So if dropDown1 = A then dropDown 2 should display "you Chose C". Pretty much a if then statement. If "a" is this then "b" is that.

Comment: Yeah, everything is predefined. If you choose something from dropDown1 it will fill dropDown2, dropDown3 and so on, with a value found in those drop downs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For predefined values like what you have, you can use the following jQuery/JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#dropDown1').change(function(){
       $('#dropDown2').val('You chose ' + this.value);
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vleong2332/82w7p0a6/

Here is the example to change dropDown1 when dropDown2 changes.
http://jsfiddle.net/vleong2332/82w7p0a6/1/

Comment: I like this, my only question is can I repeat this with multiple fields? So say I choose A in dropDown1, can it populate something from dropDown2, dropDown3, and dropDown4. Also can this be used to populate <input> fields?

Comment: You sure can, but it would help me to visualize it better if I know your markup (HTML). The JavaScript probably would have to be put into functions to avoid repetitive code.

Comment: See this. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vleong2332/82w7p0a6/2/)
Notice that I changed the values on the drop-down list to be the same but keep the text different.

Comment: Thanks a bunch man. I'll mess around with it, pretty much just needed a starting point. Now comes the fun of trying to figure it all out and modifying it to do what I want.

Comment: Any time! If this answer works for you, I'd appreciate the "accept as answer". Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, scaled down from some development I've done. A bit more flexible but also more complex. Pay attention to how the items are tagged with `data-*` attributes to decide what is hidden and shown. http://jsbin.com/siyexumulu/1/

Comment: Totally see how its more complex but I think this might actually help me in the long run with my program. Not to skilled in Java so alot of it looks like gibberish but, perfect time to learn it. Lol. Appreciate the help man.