# Show/Hide Dropbox using Radio Button and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, show-hide

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="radio" value="rural" id="rural" name="landtype" checked>Rural
<input type="radio" value="urban" id="urban" name="landtype" checked>Urban

<select id="budget1" class="dbox1">
                    <option value="9000">8000php-10000php</option>
                    <option value="13000">12000php-14000php</option>
                    <option value="17000">16000php-18000php</option>
                </select>

<select id="budget2" class="dbox2">
                    <option value="10000">9000php-11000php</option>
                    <option value="14000">12000php-15000php</option>
                    <option value="18000">17000php-19000php</option>
                </select>
```

This is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
                      $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
                           if($(this).attr("value")=="rural"){

                                document.getElementById("budget2").hide();
                                document.getElementById("budget1").show();

                           }
                           if($(this).attr("value")=="urban"){
                                document.getElementById("budget1").hide();
                                document.getElementById("budget2").show();
                           }
    });
    });

</script>
```

What I would want is that if i click my "Rural" Radio Button, "dbox2" will hide then "dbox1" will show. 
And if i click my "Urban" Radio Button, "dbox1" will hide then "dbox2" will show.

What I get so far is an "Error" from the line "`document.getElementById("budget1").hide();`" that says "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Any solution?

Comment: There is no `hide()` method on that element as is. you would need to use `$('#budget1').hide()` – See this link for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633699/selecting-an-option-from-one-drop-down-populates-other-input-fields/29634409#29634409

Comment: Also, you may want to change the event `click` chosen here: `$('input[type="radio"]').click( ...` to the event `change` so it will occur only when the value changes and not on every click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery use it and change that lines:

```
document.getElementById("budget2").hide();
document.getElementById("budget1").show();
```

to:

```
$("#budget2").hide();
$("#budget1").show();
```

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to add the ID selector.

Comment: `$("budget2").hide();
$("budget1").show();` This fails. @Red needs to use the selector syntax like so: 
`$("#budget2").hide();
$("#budget1").show();`

Answer (score 1):

hide() and show() are jQuery functions thats why you where getting those errors. use $() to get those elements and then call hide and show.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#budget2").hide();


$("#budget1").show();
```